# SQL - Left Join Into New Columns without Creating Duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a table of customers (tcustomers) based on customerid. I have another table with purchase history (tpurchasehist) and customer id. I'm trying to add twp columns to my first table-- one labeled 'Gold Member?' with values of 'Yes' if an entry in the purchases column is like '%Gold%', and another with the most recent row in the purchases column that is like '%Purchased%' or '%Returned% for a customer. My problem is I can't quite seem to figure out how to do the left join without creating any duplicates since there are multiple entries of purchases per customer id.

```
SELECT tcustomers.custid 'Customer ID',
       tcustomers.custname 'Name',
       CASE
           WHEN th.purchases LIKE '%Purchased%' THEN 'Customer Made a Purchase'
           WHEN th.purchases like '%Returned%' THEN 'Customer Made a Return'
       END 'Recent Activity',
       CASE
           WHEN th.purchases LIKE '%Gold%' THEN 'Yes'
       END 'Gold Member?'
FROM tcustomerss
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT th.custid, purchases, updated
    FROM tpurchasehist
    WHERE purchases LIKE '%Purchased%'
       or purchases like '%Returned%'
       or purchases like '%Gold%')
) th ON tcustomers.custid = th.custid
```

Comment: You need to tell us what logic you want to handle the case where there are multiple purchase events per customer.  This issue won't resolve itself automatically.

Comment: Your example is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **window functions**, first of all fetch records (Included duplicates) then use **partition by** on fetched records (treat previous query as inner query), and fetch desired output using **first** window function.